# How to keep track on network usage for long time in system monitor

Tags: network-monitoring

When I get connected to internet then I open system monitor to track the speed and total uploads and downloads. When I get disconnected and then connected to the network then in system monitor the total uploads and downloads is started from 0. Is there any way by which I can make it continue it to run and according to my need I can refresh it any time I need.

[image]

**Kidly help me. If what I need cannot be accomplised by system monitor then if possible then provide an alternative option. Thanks.**

Comment: Try nload - See my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/715554/long-network-history-in-14-04/715555#715555

Answer (score 1):

Install modem manager gui

[Modem manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWQpA.jpg)

you can find more option in this app

[image]

- open Ubuntu software center--> Edit-->software sources
- mark all

  [image]
- then open updates and choose option never for notify me of a new ubuntu version

[image]

- close it and type this command in terminal

  sudo apt-get update

  sudo apt-get upgrade

  sudo apt-get install modem-manager-gui

**if your problem not solved please inform me**.

Comment: Sir I installed it from ubuntu software center but there is a problem,  there is no option for connections and statistics, also in set limit I set a time of 5 min and in action I clicked on disconnect but after 5 min net was not disconnected only a message was shown. Kindly fix my problem. See (http://i.imgur.com/KLX7W8A.png?1)

Comment: i think your os having a trouble what's your ubuntu version?

Comment: Sir   I use ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: use this command- sudo apt-get remove modem-manager gui

Comment: i will post another answere for you please be patient!

Comment: Sir I followed the steps you suggested but I get the same behaviour as observed previously(in first comment). Kindly help resolve the issue.

Comment: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/systemd/general/ModemManager.html

Comment: refer this link