# Long Network History in 14.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, network-monitoring

I have only one minute system monitoring in my current setting. 
I would like to have longer scale.

How can you have longer timeline of network history in 14.04?

[image]

Comment: Do you need a live graph?

Comment: @muru Live graph is not necessary but would be useful. It would be nice to have a live graph but a capability of studying the history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a live view isn't needed, [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) is a great resource:

> Munin is a networked resource monitoring tool that can help analyze
>   resource trends and "what just happened to kill our performance?"
>   problems. It is designed to be very plug and play. A default
>   installation provides a lot of graphs with almost no work.

Munin generates a set of graphs usually displayed using HTML pages:

- default view (day and week):

  [image]
- ability to zoom to pretty much arbitrary timespans:

  [image]

The Ubuntu LTS Server Guide has a section on [installing and configuring Munin](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/munin.html).

By default, Munin runs as a cronjob that generates these pages about every 5 minutes. However, it can be configured to run [using CGI and be refreshed on-demand](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/MuninConfigurationMasterCGI).

Comment: I really like this answer! How can you apply your own time-series analysis on the data? How well is the integration done to R, for instance?

Comment: @Masi AFAIK Munin does not provide any APIs of its own, or integration with languages (except the little support for writing plugins that generate graphs). It uses RRD files for storing the data, and you can apply other tools to those files. Apparently there's a tool for that: http://plamendimitrov.net/blog/2014/08/09/r-package-for-working-with-rrd-files/

Comment: I asked the question in their irc channel about the API draft.

Answer (score 2):

**Try nload.** It provides live output. You can install it with `sudo apt-get install nload` or from the software center. It will provide output like this until closed:

[image]